# c++: Random access to Dynamic Array

Tags: c++, arrays, stl

Following is my scenario:

I am making use of a large  **2D dynamic array** to store elements with following attributes:

```
int
vector
```

Now, the array elements are accessed randomly. As a result, time access to elements greatly varies.

I want time access to elements to be small as well as constant for all the accessions.

Is dynamic array best suitable for my scenario?

I tries using unordered_map of boost but it seems that unordered map takes more time to access elements as compared to dynamic array.

Please give suggestions:

Code:

**Code:**

```
for( counter1=0; counter1< sizeof(chunk1); ++counter1)
{
   //code lines skipped
    IndexEntries &data=IndexTable[chunk1[counter1]][chunk1[counter1+1]];
    DoubleTableEntries &GetValue=NewDoubleTable[NextState_chunk1][data.index]; 
    NextState_chunk1= GetValue.Next_State;
    ++Bcount;
    buffer[ Bcount]=NextState_chunk1;
    ++counter1;

    //  Code lines skipped
}
```

Here NewDoubleTable is the 2d Array from which I am accessing randomly elements.

Comment: *By what* are you accessing? Do you *search* for some `int`? Do you index the 2D array? Please give an example declaration and access.

Comment: @delnan I specify particular indexes to access the element.I have added the code.

Comment: If your indices are random, then your performance is always going to be poor, unfortunately.

Comment: *As a result, time access to elements greatly varies*. Is this assumption verified by a profiling session? Afaik you might have performance issues (and guessing is not the way to find them) but as long as no profile support it, you have none in this area.

Comment: As user3521733 stated, if your indices are random, for large size arrays, your performance is going to be poor due to a potentially large number of cache misses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing that can beat an array access in terms of speed, all the higher level containers like `unordered_map<>` *add additional work*. When you can use a plain array or `vector<>`, that is always the fastest you can get.

You need `unordered_map<>` only if you have a sparsely populated keyspace which prohibits use of a plain array/vector due to space considerations. In that case, the `unordered_map<>` can translate the keys in the sparse keyspace to a hash index into the tightly populated hash table, which in turn is nothing more or less than an array.

Answer (score 1):

For random access, nothing can beat array (dynamic or not). Only this data structure provides O(1) access time on an average because the it uses consecutive memory.